# Facebook Marketing API - Validate ad settings

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Before creating new campaign, adset and ad I would like to check whether my campaing, adset and ad settings are correct - for example: if my ad can be shown on Messenger Inbox placement with all the other settings set up (objective, optimization goal, image etc.).

I was searching through the documentation looking for some endpoint and I have found only Ad Recommendation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-recommendation/ but it seems that it works only on already created ads. In my case, I would like to validate **before** creating campaign/adset/ad.

Have someone of you encountered such endpoint? Or found a smart way to do such validation?